# exhaustmap in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I would like to ask what is the best practice or how to use exhaust Matp to prevent multiple submissions ? like for example when user spam the SAVE button ? for example based on the sample code below , how do we handle it that it would only submit 1 at a time even the user spam or click the save button hundred times. Thanks.

#html code

```
 <ng-template #editButtons>
      <div class="flex" *ngIf="isEditing">
        <app-page-section-cards-btn
          [btnData]="pageSectionsOptions.btnData.cancel"
          (btnClickEvent)="cancelEdit()"></app-page-section-cards-btn>
        <app-page-section-cards-btn
          [btnData]="pageSectionsOptions.btnData.save"
          (btnClickEvent)="saveDeal()">
      </app-page-section-cards-btn>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
```

#ts code

```
 saveDeal(){
    this.isLoading = true;
    if(!this.isExistingDeal){     
      const dealTypeValues = {
        "id": 0,
        "name": this.dealPLSFormFields.dealName,
        "summary": this.dealPLSFormFields.summary,
        "mlasId": this.dealPLSFormFields.partner,
        "startDate": "estimatedOtherRevenue":this.dealPLSFormFields.estimatedOtherRevenue,
        "descriptionOfOtherRevenue":this.dealPLSFormFields.descriptionOfOtherRevenue,
        "totalMonthlyRentAndFees":this.dealPLSFormFields.totalMonthlyRentAndFees,
        "buildOutCostReimbursement":this.dealPLSFormFields.buildOutCostReimbursement,
        "dealId": 0,
        "startDateString": AppUtils.convertDateStringToYYYYMMDD(this.dealPLSFormFields.startDate),
        "endDateString":  AppUtils.convertDateStringToYYYYMMDD(this.dealPLSFormFields.endDate),
      } 
     
      const payload = {
        "id": 0,
        "name": this.dealPLSFormFields.dealName,
        "dealType": "Partner Location Submission",
        "annualRentProposed": null,
        "annualRentCurrent": null,
        "firmTermRemaining": null,
        "firmTermAdded": null,
        "maxAvailableTerm": null,
        "status": null,
        "capitalContribution": null,
        "parentCloneId": null,
        "accountId": this.currentAccount.accountId,
        "transactionId": this.transactionData.id,
        "dealTypeValues": JSON.stringify(dealTypeValues)
      }
      this._dealService.createDeal(payload)
      .pipe(debounceTime(500))
      .subscribe(
        res=>{
          this.isLoading = false;
          this._notificationService.showSuccess('Deal was successfully created.');
          if(res.isSuccess){
            this.refreshDealDetailsPage(res.data);
          }  
        },
        err=>{
          console.log('Error creating deal')
        }
      )
    }else{

      const dealTypeValues = {
        "id": this.dealData.dealTypeValues.id,
        "name": this.dealPLSFormFields.dealName,
        "summary": this.dealPLSFormFields.summary,
        "mlasId": this.dealPLSFormFields.partner,
        "startDate": AppUtils.convertDateStringToYYYYMMDD(this.dealPLSFormFields.startDate),
        "endDate": AppUtils.convertDateStringToYYYYMMDD(this.dealPLSFormFields.endDate),
        "securityMonitoringMonthly": this.dealPLSFormFields.securityMonitoringMonthly,
        "rent": this.dealPLSFormFields.rent,
        "cam": this.dealPLSFormFields.cam,
        "supportServicesFee": this.dealPLSFormFields.supportServicesFee,
        "estimatedOtherRevenue":this.dealPLSFormFields.estimatedOtherRevenue,
        "descriptionOfOtherRevenue":this.dealPLSFormFields.descriptionOfOtherRevenue,
        "totalMonthlyRentAndFees":this.dealPLSFormFields.totalMonthlyRentAndFees,
        "buildOutCostReimbursement":this.dealPLSFormFields.buildOutCostReimbursement,
        "dealId": this.dealData.dealTypeValues.dealId,
        "startDateString": AppUtils.convertDateStringToYYYYMMDD(this.dealPLSFormFields.startDate),
        "endDateString":  AppUtils.convertDateStringToYYYYMMDD(this.dealPLSFormFields.endDate),
      } 

      const payload = {
        "id": this.dealData.id,
        "name": this.dealPLSFormFields.dealName,
        "dealType": "Partner Location Submission",
        "annualRentProposed": null,
        "annualRentCurrent": null,
        "firmTermRemaining": null,
        "firmTermAdded": null,
        "maxAvailableTerm": null,
        "status": this.dealData.status,
        "capitalContribution": null,
        "parentCloneId": null,
        "accountId": this.currentAccount.accountId,
        "transactionId": this.transactionData.id,
        "dealTypeValues": JSON.stringify(dealTypeValues)
      }
      
      this._dealService.updateDeal(payload)
      .pipe(debounceTime(500))
      .subscribe(
        res=>{
          if(res.isSuccess){
            this.isLoading = false;
            this.refreshDealDetailsPage(res.data);
          }  
        },
        err=>{
          this.isLoading = false;
          console.log('Error updating deal')
        }
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Check if [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-evzceu) helps

Comment: @navnath is it necessary to create all those code blocks just to try the exhaustMap Sir ?

Comment: what is code inside refreshDealDetailsPage?  I'd just redirect to some other page or refresh current page

Comment: yea @navnath. Also save deal has 2 options createDispositionDeal and updateDispositionDeal

Comment: @navnath can you pease check my updated code above Sir ?

Comment: @MartinLaurz inside `saveDeal` at first line you can do check like `if(this.isLoading) return;`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69613031/how-to-check-if-form-fields-are-valid?noredirect=1#comment123045103_69613031

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to approach this:

1. One is to use RxJS operator [debounceTime](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/debouncetime).
   This operator only allows 1 request per X milliseconds to pass through the observable pipe that will be called by the subscribe. So even if the user spams it only one will go through per X amount of time. This can be useful in all types of requests and not only saves.

   In your case, let's say for 500 milliseconds:

   ```
    import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';

    ...

    this._dealService.createDeal(payload)
      .pipe(debounceTime(500))
      .subscribe(
    ...
   ```

Edit: the exhaustMap [solution suggested by Yuriy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69604987/5682680) can be an even better alternative to this, since if the request is slower than 500ms then we could allow double submit with this solution

2. The other way of approaching this is to disable the button when its clicked for the first time and until we get a response (success or error) from the backend:

   ```
    import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

    ...

    this._dealService.createDeal(payload)
    .pipe(
      tap(() => this.saving = true),
      finalize(() => this.saving = false),
    ).subscribe(
    ...
   ```

   and then you can add the disabled logic in your `app-page-section-cards-btn` component

   ```
    <app-page-section-cards-btn
      [disabled]="saving"
      [btnData]="pageSectionsOptions.btnData.save"
      (btnClickEvent)="saveDeal()">
   ```

A combination of both could be really robust but can add a lot of boilerplate code in all your components if you have this behaviour all around your app. A suggestion could be then to do the `debounceTime` logic in a global interceptor  of the 1) part.

Comment: what is the ideal debounce time ? I tried 500 ms and I spammed click it still created tons of request

Comment: 500ms should be more than enough to not spam requests at least. I would say at most 2000ms = 2 seconds. 
But as mentioned in edit, for your particular case, even better than `debounceTime` would be using `exhaustMap` instead since then you only make a request if the previous one is complete. 
Also, give the disabling button a try - usually this is better UX, especially if you also show a spinner in the button - then the user knows he/she has to wait instead of spamming

Comment: do you have an exhaustMap implementation example ?

Answer (score 1):

There is two ways for preventing multiple submission.

- Create variable/subject to hold info that request is pending/loading
  and disable a button
- Create subject for login event.

> ```
> this.loginSubject$.pipe(
>     exhaustMap((loginData) => this.authService.login(loginData))
> );
> ```